# Splitting List That Contains Strings and Integers

Tags: python, string, list, integer

```
myList = [ 4,'a', 'b', 'c', 1 'd', 3]
```

how to split this list into two list that one contains strings and other contains integers in *elegant/pythonic* way?

output:

```
myStrList = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]

myIntList = [ 4, 1, 3 ]
```

NOTE: didn't implemented such a  list, just thought about how to find an elegant answer (is there any?) to such a problem.

Comment: I think you need a regular expression

Comment: imho, it is very ugly solution.i'd rather iterate over list and split.

Comment: Inspecting types is nonpythonic to begin with, as is creating such a mixed-type list. Maybe you should see about splitting the data based on its *purpose* on input, instead of hacking around it later?

Comment: this is imaginary list (didnt implemented it though), i just wonder is there any elegant solution on this problem.

Comment: @bozdoz -- a regex will choke if you try to pass it an integer (won't it?)

Comment: Voting to close, since you're asking for an elegant solution to a problem you don't actually face and that no one writing elegant code will ever face. (Also because you don't answer the implied "what have you tried?")

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As others have mentioned in the comments, you should really start thinking about how you can get rid of the list which holds in-homogeneous data in the first place.  However, if that really *can't* be done, I'd use a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for x in myList:
   d[type(x)].append(x)

print d[int]
print d[str]
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use list comprehension: -

```
>>> myList = [ 4,'a', 'b', 'c', 1, 'd', 3]
>>> myIntList = [x for x in myList if isinstance(x, int)]
>>> myIntList
[4, 1, 3]
>>> myStrList = [x for x in myList if isinstance(x, str)]
>>> myStrList
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: This works well if the types are known ahead of time and there aren't too many of them :)

Comment: Use ````dtype```` as ````float```` instead of ````int````if the numbers in the list are float values. Otherwise, ````myIntList```` will return an empty list.

Answer (score 3):

```
def filter_by_type(list_to_test, type_of):
    return [n for n in list_to_test if isinstance(n, type_of)]

myList = [ 4,'a', 'b', 'c', 1, 'd', 3]
nums = filter_by_type(myList,int)
strs = filter_by_type(myList,str)
print nums, strs

>>>[4, 1, 3] ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 3):

Split the list according to types found in the orginal list

```
myList = [ 4,'a', 'b', 'c', 1, 'd', 3]
types = set([type(item) for item in myList])
ret = {}
for typeT in set(types):
    ret[typeT] = [item for item in myList if type(item) == typeT]

>>> ret
{<type 'str'>: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], <type 'int'>: [4, 1, 3]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to summarize this thread by answering a Python FAQ "how do you write a method that takes arguments in any order, of a narrow range of types?"

Assuming the left-to-right order of all the arguments are not important, try this (based on @mgilson 's answer):

```
def partition_by_type(args, *types):
    d = defaultdict(list)

    for x in args:
        d[type(x)].append(x)

    return [ d[t] for t in types ]

def cook(*args):
    commands, ranges = partition_by_type(args, str, range)

    for range in ranges:
        for command in commands:
            blah blah blah...
```

Now you can call `cook('string', 'string', range(..), range(..), range(..))`. The argument order is stable, within its type.

```
# TODO  make the strings collect the ranges, preserving order
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code as an example to create two different lists by using the function isdigit(),which checks for integers in a string.

```
ip=['a',1,2,3]
m=[]
n=[]
for x in range(0,len(ip):
    if str(ip[x]).isdigit():
        m.append(ip[x])
    else:n.append(ip[x])
print(m,n)
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect and contains an error. Incorrect because with `isdigit()` you check whether the element is a string that only contains a number, but does not separate a number from a string (since you can apply it for strings). e.g. the list `['a','b',1,2,3,'10']` will return `[2, 3, 4, 5] ['a', 'b']` instead of `[1,2,3]['a','b','10']`. This brings me to the error: in appending to `m` you should append `ip[x]`. Remark, it's better to use `len(ip)` than hardcoding the length.

Comment: I noticed that mistake now because I was using isdigit to return the position of a number in the list. Thanks

Comment: You still can't distinguish `10` and `'10'`.

Comment: It is because I converted the whole list to a string in order to use isdigit that's why it won't differentiate between them. :)

Comment: Yes I know that, so you agree that you're not answering OP's question?

Comment: Technically I answered his question though it may not satisfy yours.  :)

Comment: Consider the following array that has 3 integers and 2 strings: `ip=['a',1,'10',2,3]`. Please plug this into your code and tell me how long `m` and `n` are.

Comment: m has length 4 and n has length 1. I told uh that i convert whole list to string so no diff b/w 10 and '10'.

Comment: Indeed. This means that the original list, should have had 4 integers and 1 string. But it had 3 integers and 2 strings. Hence your code doesn't split the list correctly. Please change your code so that it is correct, without repeating other answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = (input("Enter  string and digits: "))
d=[]
s=[]
for  x in range(0,len(n)):
    if str(n[x]).isdigit():
        d.append(n[x])
    else
        s.append(n[x])
print(d)
print(s)
```

**Edit 1: Here is another solution**

```
import re
x = input("Enter any string that contains characters and integers: ")
s = re.findall('[0-9]',x)
print(s)
c = re.findall('[a-z/A-Z]',x)
print(c)
```

Comment: @oguzismail wrong. Code-only answers [should not be deleted from review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256359/flag-try-this-code-answers-as-very-low-quality)

Comment: @Zoe well, they should be

Comment: please explain @oguzismail

Answer (score 0):

```
myList = [ 4,'a', 'b', 'c', 1 'd', 3]

myList_string = []
myList_number = []

for a in myList:
  if type(a) == int or type(a) == float:
    myList_number.append(a)
  elif type(a) == str:
    myList_string.append(a)
```

Comment: There are **eight existing answers** to this question, including a top-voted, accepted answer with **sixteen votes**. Are you _certain_ your solution hasn't already been given? If not, why do you believe your approach improves upon the existing proposals, which have been validated by the community? Offering an explanation is _always_ useful on Stack Overflow, but it's _especially_ important where the question has been resolved to the satisfaction of both the OP and the community. Help readers out by explaining what your answer does different and when it might be preferred.

Answer (score -1):

```
import strings;
num=strings.digits;
str=strings.letters;
num_list=list()
str_list=list()
for i in myList:
    if i in num:
        num_list.append(int(i))
    else:
        str_list.append(i)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.