# How to separate out integer and string elements from a list into two different list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to separate out integer and string element from a list into two different list.
i.e.

```
list1=[1,"Red",2,"Blue",3,"Pink",4,"White",5,"Yellow"]
```

separate into

```
intList=[1,2,3,4,5]
strList=["Red","Blue","Pink","White","Yellow"]
```

I write this code

```
import string
digits=string.digits
strings=string.letters + '_' + digits
list1=[1,"Red",2,"Blue",3,"Pink",4,"White",5,"Yellow"]
number=[]
string=[]
for item in list1:
    if item in digits:
        number.append(item)
    if item in strings:
        string.append(item)
print "List of String is:",string
print "List of Digits is:",number
```

but it gives an error: " 'in ' requires string as left operand, not int"

How to write this program into another way?

Comment: I believe you want `isinstance(..., int)` to check if something is a number

Comment: Note that `strings` is a string of characters, usually `'1234567890'`. You can only contains-test against this with other strings Hence the error message, which informs you of the type mismatch, since `1` is not a string. And yes, use `isinstance()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make function to separate those out for you whether they be in any order

```
def separate(array, type):
    return [n for n in array if isinstance(n, type)]

array = [ 1,"Red",2,"Blue",3,"Pink",4,"White",5,"Yellow"]
digits = separate(myList,int)
strings = array(myList,str)
print digits, strings
```

for further help please see
 [Python - Splitting List That Contains Strings and Integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776980/python-splitting-list-that-contains-strings-and-integers)

Comment: This is python2, so `isinstance(x, (int, long))` is probably a good idea.